# Very specific parsing in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, ifstream, stringstream

Basically, I'm trying to read in the words from a file and, without punctuation, read each word into a multimap which is then inserted into a vector with each pair being a word and the line of the file that word is found. I've got the function to remove punctuation working perfectly and I'm fairly certain my insert code works properly, but I can't seem to get around the line number part. I've included this section of my code as follows:

```
ifstream in("textfile.txt");
string line;
string keys;
stringstream keystream;
int line_number = 1;
while (getline(in, line, '\n')) {
        alphanum(line);


        keystream << line;


        while(getline(keystream, keys, ' ')) 
            table.insert(keys, line_number); //this just inserts the pair into my  vector (table is an instance of a class I created)
        keystream.str("");


        line_number++;
}
```

The problem seems to be related to the `stringstream`. It doesn't seem to clear when I use `keystream.str("")`. This particular method only seems to read line 1 in and then exits the loop, whereas some other variations I've tried (I can't remember exactly what I did) read the entire file but don't flush the `stringstream` so it reads like word 1, word 1, word 2, word 1, word 2, word 3, etc.. Anyway, if anyone could point me in the right direction or perhaps link to a guide specific to parsing input in c++ that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep the string stream object; just make a new one in each round:

```
string line;
while (getline(in, line, '\n'))
{
    alphanum(line);
    istringstream keystream(line);

    string keys;
    while (getline(keystream, keys, ' '))  // or even "while (keystream >> keys)"
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the second getline() loop sets the EOF flag on the stringstream, and this is not cleared when you call str(). You need to call .clear() also on 'keystream'.

Comment: It looks like both of these answers work. Thanks guys! I tried the .clear() thing earlier and it didn't work so I guess I just had it in the wrong place or something.

Comment: +1. I remember having this issue a few years back, I used to recreate the `stringstream` through each iteration of the loop until I discovered that you can clear the EOF flag.